# Character table of a group determines the set of commutators of the group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

We write $[x,y]$ for the commutator $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ of $x$ and $y$ in a group $G$.

(A) Let $g \in G$  and fix $x \in G$. Show that $g$ is conjugate to $[x,y]$ for some $y \in G$ iff

$$\sum_{\chi \in \text{Irr}(G)} \frac{|\chi(x)|^{2}\bar{\chi(g)}}{\chi(1)} \neq 0.$$

(B) Show that if $g=[x,y]$ for some $x,y \in G$ iff

$$\sum_{\chi \in \text{Irr}(G)} \frac{\chi(g)}{\chi(1)} \neq 0.$$

I have done the first part. I think that second part is just applying the first part in a correct way but I cannot do it. This problem is important in the sense that it determines all the commutators of a group from the character table. The set of commutator generally does not form a subgroup. Any hint or solution will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Fix $g$ and sum the first formula over all $x \in G.$

Comment: Is this homework? It certainly looks like it.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson Can you elaborate to some extent. I do understand that since g is a commutator all its conjugate are commutator.Is this the fact that is being is used. Secondly in the first case the sum is nonzero but does it means if we run the sum over all elements of G it still remains nonzero.

Comment: @ David Handelman No this is not. I am reading character theory of finite groups on my own. This is my own endeavour to try out these problem and I am keen to find out how much you can tell about a group from its character table.

Comment: If you have correctly proved the first part, you will know that the first sum given is non-negative for any $x,g,$ and that for a fixed choice of $x,g$ it is strictly positive if and only if $g$ is a commutator of the form asked for in the first part of the question. Clearly a sum of non-negative real quantities is non-negative, and is strictly positive if and only if one of the terms in the sum is strictly positive.

Comment: Yeah I got it.. It was just a little tricky. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson Can you suggest me some article where I can find more interesting results like this.. more precisely saying I want to know how much you can you tell about a group from its character table.I know that you can talk about all normal subgroup, the center, the commutator subgroup, the size of the centralized of each element , whether a group is nilpotent or not and this current question about the set of commutators. Thanks!

Comment: There are many paper on such questions, eg by Isaacs and his students, and by G. Navarro. There is a generalizaton of the above commutator result givenn as an exercise in Burnside's book: an element $g \in G$ is expressible as a product of $n$ commutators if and only if $\sum_{\chi \in {\rm Irr}(G)} \frac{\chi(g)}{\chi(1)^{2n-1}} \neq 0.$

Comment: For future reference: if you are quoting exercises from a book, it is good manners to give the actual citation (e.g. Isaacs's book). The way you phrased your questions suggests very strongly that they are someone else's words, so you should acknowledge that, to help people appreciate the context and motivation for the questions

Comment: (This is indeed Exercise 3.10 from Isaacs's Character Theory book.)

Comment: Concerning your broader question in your comment: There is a question of Jim Humphreys on this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/97589